# Downloading Google Maps municipal geometry

Tags: geometry, google-maps-api

When searching for a city on google maps, google is that smart it displays a geometry line on the boundary off the municipal.
See this link: http://g.co/maps/23dz5

Is there a place in the google maps api where I can download this geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you are searching city boundries of world. and you can get it anywhere when you find free data...there is lots of option but which country are you interested in?

For free shapefile you can use :

1. [Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country) - you can download by countrty...

or if you want whole world :

2. Whole World version 2.0 as [Shapefile](http://www.gadm.org/data2/gadm_v2_shp.zip), or ESRI geodatabase (for ArcMap 10): [ESRI file geodatabase](http://www.gadm.org/data2/gadm_v2_gdb.zip), [ESRI personal geodatabase](http://www.gadm.org/data2/gadm_v2_mdb.zip).

The coordinate reference system is latitude/longitude and theWGS84 datum.

And don’t forget:

> These data are freely available for academic and other non-commercial
>   use. Redistribution, or commercial use, is not allowed without prior
>   permission.

Comment: The data Google has is vastly better than any of the publicly available data. There is no free equivalent to the data they have.

Comment: If it just needs to make a query over these areas,e.g. "Return me all points inside area London" ,I think this is possible with Google Places api,isn't it?

Comment: @ChristopherSchmidt you think this is still true `The data Google has is vastly better than any of the publicly available data.` ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: no, there isn't. If you need the data but don't want to invest lots of money, you could use the data provided by OpenStreetMap. I have found it to be reasonably accurate at least throughout Europe.

Comment: Even on Openstreemp,there are shapefiles for the boundaries on the level of city,not subareas/smaller areas...If you want more details,you need to pay.