# Google Maps: obtaining the border of an area

Tags: google-maps

When using the geocode API it is easy to obtain the (centre of the) coordinates of the address. For example: [Rotterdam](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Rotterdam). If you look up the same location in Google Maps you also get the [surface area of Rotterdam](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=rotterdam&hl=nl&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=39.507908,72.509766&t=v&hnear=Rotterdam,+Zuid-Holland,+Nederland&z=12).

I would like to do the same using the API, is this possible?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think that it is not possible because it is pre-cached map or server side generated map...but i dont know if there is any service about it or not.. you can look image [here](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@177170827,highlight:0x47c5b7605f54c47d:0x5229bbac955e4b85@1%7Cstyle:maps&hl=nl&src=app&x=2098&y=1353&z=12&s=Galileo)...

[image: googlemap]

and there was a question as your question. and my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24294/3071)...

i hope it hels you...